# Meteor Down SSL support

Tags: meteor

I use to test my Meteor app, "meteor down". I am totally happy with this tool, but when I switched to https, it does not work anymore.

I only get this output:

```
Time   : 10/31/2016, 9:06:52 AM
--------------------------------------------------
Time   : 10/31/2016, 9:06:57 AM
--------------------------------------------------
Time   : 10/31/2016, 9:07:02 AM
--------------------------------------------------
Time   : 10/31/2016, 9:07:07 AM
--------------------------------------------------
Time   : 10/31/2016, 9:07:12 AM
--------------------------------------------------
Time   : 10/31/2016, 9:07:17 AM
```

Here is my configuration:

```
meteorDown.run({
    concurrency: 10,
    url: 'https://example.com'
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

After I use the fork, something has changed. But unfortunately I am getting an error now:

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/lib/node_modules/meteor-down/lib/mdown.js:47
    if(error) throw error;
              ^
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Here is my new configuration:

```
meteorDown.run({
    concurrency: 10,
    url: 'wss://example.com/websocket'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are ok (it's not you!), there is an outstanding pull request on the meteor down package to allow use of secure web sockets as well as regular ones.

https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-down/pull/20/commits/68a297ac987390b4df1f2e8e616e118d8291a4ce

You should ask for the author to accept the PR, or use the fork

https://github.com/louis49/meteor-down